# My Geely car transmission signal blinking in dashboard

Tags: transmission, cvt-transmission

I have Geely Emgrand EC7 2013 CVT model.

From past three months crackling sound in transmission when i am slow the car like 30,20 speed..yesterday suddenly all transmission signal P D N blinking and not accelerating. And then Off and On engine everything is ok.

Actually what's the problem in my car?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you had the codes read?

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply.Yes code check is fine...

Answer (score 0):

Please check the brake switch, when it start malfunctioning I found the same case, mechanics went mad trying to figure it out, but it was just a simple brake switch.